# Summing the Digits of a Number

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

### Challenge

- Given a non-negative integer, find the sum of its digits.

#### Rules

- Your program must take a non-negative integer as input.
- Your program should output the sum of the digits of the input integer.
- Your program should be able to handle inputs up to 10^100.

#### Examples

- If the input is 123, the output should be 6 (1 + 2 + 3).
- If the input is 888, the output should be 24 (8 + 8 + 8).
- If the input is 1024, the output should be 7 (1 + 0 + 2 + 4).
- If the input is 3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592, the output should be 315.

#### Format

- Your program should take input from standard input (stdin) and output the result to standard output (stdout).
- Your program should be runnable in a Unix-like environment.

#### Test cases

Input:

```
123
```

Output:

```
6
```

Input:

```
888
```

Output:

```
24
```

Input:

```
1024
```

Output:

```
7
```

Input:

```
3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592
```

Output:

```
315
```

#### Scoring

- This is a code-golf challenge, so the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: I have a feeling this is a duplicate...

Comment: this is [OEIS A007953](https://oeis.org/A007953)

Comment: Can I take it as an array with 1 element in it?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75384/equality-in-the-sum-of-digits)

Comment: Congrats on finding a non duplicate challenge which can have [an answer of *0 bytes*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258233/76594)

Comment: @Surb [1](/a/235581) [2](/a/195218) [3](/a/251638) [4](/a/108068) [5](/a/248138) [6](/a/231503) [7](/a/247195) ... there's plenty more

Comment: Can we input and/or output as a `String`?

Answer (score 11):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 15 bytes

```
'0.<"@(+>i(^-<!
```

Test it on [the online interpreter](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/#%270.%3C%22%40(%2B%3Ei(%5E-%3C!)!

---

Roughly equivalent to this C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int total = 0;
    int i;
    while ((i = getchar()) != EOF) {
        total += i - '0';
    }
    printf("%d\n", total);
}
```

Control flow is kinda weird so it actually calls `getchar()` a couple times even after EOF is reached.

---

Unfolds to this:

```
    '
   0 .
  < " @
 ( + > i
( ^ - < !
```

With code paths highlighted:

[image]

Control flow starts at the north corner heading southwest (on the red path). Instructions are executed as follows:

- `'0`: Push a 0 to the stack
- `<`: Change the direction of control flow

  (Walk off the edge of the grid and wrap around)
- `i`: Get a single character from stdin (-1 on EOF) and push it to the stack
- `>`: Branch on the sign of the top of the stack

If the value is positive (any character that isn't EOF), the IP takes the green path:

- `"0`: Push the value of the character '0' (i.e. 48) to the stack
- `-`: Subtract the two values on top of the stack
- `+`: Add the two values on top of the stack
- `<`: Redirect control flow, merging with the red path

Once EOF is read, the IP takes the blue path, printing out the stored value... eventually. As you can see from the image it takes the scenic route.

- `-`: Subtract the two values on top of the stack. There's now only one value, `total - -1` (i.e. `total + 1`).
- `i`: Attempt to read another character from stdin (always sees EOF)
- `<`: Redirect control flow
- `-` Subtract the two values on top of the stack. Again, there's now only one value: `total + 2`.
- `^`: Redirect control flow
- `((`: Decrement the top of the stack twice, undoing the effects of `i-i-`.
- `!`: Print the value on top of the stack as a decimal integer
- `i`: Another attempt to read stdin, though at this point the values on the stack don't matter
- `@`: End program.

Comment: And if anyone wants to make a tool like HexagonyColorer so I can make the diagrams look nice instead of hand-drawing them in paint, that'd be appreciated. If not I'll just keep doing them in paint, I don't honestly care enough to make a tool of my own.

Answer (score 9):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 30 bytes

```c
f(int*s){s=*s?*s-48+f(s+1):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYxNDoIwEEb3nIJgTFoQ03amdEb8uYBHcGOKKImisbginB2Je/mW7@V9Pr96P461aNouDbIPuzQc0pAjZbUImZYbVQ7jomn9/VNd4m3oqua5vu2jaArix7lphYz6KJ72ek@oFsmyOrXJKq7FMdEGEinLf5qI5rRWBuc8aNSWTWHBEjsGA4SFKRCAwDi2yhChZqcLBmZwVitLRrFDRpzC3/cwfgE)

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 31 bytes

```c
f(*s){return*s?*s-48+f(s+1):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcxBDoIwEAXQPacgGJMWxLSdKZ1RoxfwCG4IiJJoNRRWxLMjcS9/@V/@r/LqUfrbNDUiDXLsrv3Q@TSc0pAjZY0ImZY7tf9Mq9ZXj6G@xofQ1@1rez9GUev7@Fm2XshojOI5726uGpGs64tPNnEjzok2kEi5/8dEtMRaGVxy0Kgtm8KCJXYMBggLUyAAgXFslSFCzU4XDMzgrFaWjGKHjDgPf9@f6Qs)

## [C89](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 35 bytes

```c
f(char*s){return*s?*s-48+f(s+1):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/NasMwEITvegrjUrCcuEhaydqt@/MivRjJTgSpEiwnl5BXryrSczOnYT5mYFy3cy7nuXH7cWkTvy7Tel5imz7b1GnczE3aSP4qhlt@CtEdzn6q3tLqw/Fl/8FYiCv7HkNsLsfgObuyqui0lHhu6mf/FettVZxUUHM@/EMR8QGVQukHGKSWhlRvwCBZAgWoe9VrAARlyQiFqCVZ2RMQgTVSGFSCrCatS/E@fd/@e16Jgd3yj5sP4y7lrlx9d0i5O01@jGtwvw)

Answer (score 8):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 0 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiIiwiIiwiNjk0MjAiXQ==)

That's right. No bytes needed.

Alternatively

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiJEiLCIiLCI2OTQyMCJd)

Just the built-in that works on numbers

Comment: 0 bytes is a really cool one and quite rare!

Comment: @lyxal I think no answer can defeat you now, you rock

Comment: Make an answer that also optimises your hard drive to save memory

Comment: @AitzazImtiaz FYI, it's discouraged to accept answers on CGCC. Answers aren't all competing with each other, they're competing within languages, so there's no one winner per se. An accepted answer might also discourage more answers to your question. I'd suggest unaccepting this answer.

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 23 bytes

```javascript
n=>eval([...n].join`+`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxNCoMwEEDhfY/hSikNmZ8kMwt7kVIwWC2KJFKL109dF7cfvDfHPW79Z1q/t5RfQxnbktr7sMelfhhj0tPMeUrdtWtKn9OWl8Es@V2PdQVIVdNc/lREThQs8gkTMDhF78iJBiUkYY@eiYQwqLMowqABvJIqBQfWCVoNrMxHeCzLDw)

Takes input as a string

### [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 26 bytes

```javascript
n=>eval([...""+n].join`+`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcixDoIwEADQ3a@4MEGIRdCBBT7A1dGYcIEDSpo7Qg/072tX4/KGt@CBvt/sqmeWgcLYBG5aOtClT2NMkuT8MotY7vIuC72wF0fGyZSOaVlds@z0e3Vd/115qW4xiwIcegWlSI@ewHpQkbjbRDDKBvdHDJiRB0fwtjrLrrB7yxPQZxUmVosOWBTVCocv)

Takes input as a number, doesn't work if the number is too large for JavaScript to stringify naturally

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with taking the input as a string, which would save you 3 bytes and allow to support the last test case.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 24 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(map(int,n))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY7chJzk1ISFfKsiktzNXITCzQy80p08jQ1IdIbC4qAfI00oGhBaYmGJkx8wWJDI2MIEwA)

Input as a string.

### [Python](https://www.python.org), 29 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(map(int,str(n)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhZ7cxJzk1ISFfKsiktzNXITCzQy80p0ikuKNPI0NTUharYVFAEFNdJAUkBcUFqioQmXXLDY0MgYwgQA)

Input as an integer.

Answer (score 7):

> NOTE: Since many/most of the answers seem to ignore the requirement in the question that the input must be taken from `stdin` and the output must be sent to `stdout`, I suppose it is reasonable if I do so, too. I think that's a silly and arbitrary requirement, because it makes many languages non-competitive. The standard on Code Golf is to [allow functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422), and to [allow functions taking input via arguments and outputting via their return value(s)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447), so this is what I will follow.

## x86-64 Assembly, standard Linux calling convention, 17 bytes

```
64 31 C0 0F B6 0F E3 09 48 FF C7 8D 44 01 D0 EB F2 C3
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFfa8IwFMWfcz9FKIgbU2mb1iaDDfxTnwYb05ehY8S2SkaalrSO6pd3UatUxsA@BHryu@fce8OLIkmXcttdR9G@J1SZyK9iq0peYZXlOlmJaj/dpGOxFmXxCKjKNEp41cHmgJcsy42WZj@7CiWRUYcfsxC/zd7xXMfiE9C3jqodClUMSKgIGRGQTPjJYm4u8QPWJquL23b7wKc5OriCKTHOOin3vbXMlhKnXCiAEZfRQMVjUeSSb0/ZSBeig4/WEZcSXdo93SZx3W39Z9jXyWQazvAk0ykvp6UGXH/H@lybNayO4QCH2HNMo3RQZ133A3/B4a3g6FZwfCsY/gOeh716yrN4HPqyGDN5jxeR2GHrstW7VnG/KJ@eF2Vrs1AWDBqQ4xILhg2BUmrBqEnYrmfBuKEQx3N85vZ94lMWMOIS6vXdvkcIJW7AfNul1HNY4PQZYYwEvmP71LVZ4DHPM4UWhA03C/a/)**

This is a minor, iterative improvement on [qwr's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258254), which is 18 bytes.

It saves 1 byte by using the relatively-obscure `JECXZ` instruction (actually `JRCXZ`, since this is 64-bit mode), which jumps if the value of the `rcx` register is zero.

It also improves on qwr's original (arguably fixes a bug?) in that it supports the case where the input is an empty string, returning a sum of zero. (To be fair, the challenge doesn't specify whether it is required to handle this, so maybe it cannot be termed a "bug", and, in fact, my next attempt will have this same "bug", so I can hardly ding qwr for taking advantage of it, too!)

```
SumDigits:
  31 C0         xor    eax, eax
Loop:
  0F B6 0F      movzx  ecx, BYTE PTR [rdi]
  E3 09         jrcxz  End
  48 FF C7      inc    rdi
  8D 44 01 D0   lea    eax, [rcx + rax - '0']
  EB F2         jmp    Loop
End:
  C3            ret    ; result is in eax
```

## x86-64 Assembly, fully custom calling convention, 14 bytes

```
64 31 C0 31 D2 AC 8D 54 02 D0 38 26 75 F7 C3
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFva9swEMZfS5/icCndaBpsy46tQAf547wqbCx5M5pRFNtNVGTJSPLq9MunSppmDmMQIQS6@z3P6U7MmLJaie3dOs93fS5tKZ7MVlrWglS1Lp95u5s31ZSvuTVDfIVyUaAreC0hZxKYMU1Vgt0w6w5uwG0mXtnWQC5KpkFJeOCyaTFqlUYla3vgjuOt2N@KFj8oVQ8xEqowK@fNRA/GvxYZ/Fj8hEdt@G@XK9kH/6iLFm5Bu/fdwY1/43J5VaNzvgdsg9GLfEN7a5zJwtnr0u76a6FWAirGJcYTJvKRLKbc1IJtHVE3ZoOc3lkyIdCpbZdR9UeiUn@QLngPvs9m82wBM6UrZudWYziug7TWbpLPh5oY76sNj1LzVzo6ljl/Bv4XHF8KTi4Fp5eC2X/Az2bPPvUzeGj6NBjXeZ@ZnL@Bdxrol2vzdWnvvy3tdbOUHh51oCAkHh53AmmaenjSJfww8vC0EyFBFMQ0HMQkTmlCSUjSaBAOIkJSEiY09sM0jQKaBANKKCVJHPhxGvo0iWgUOaGHs46bh3fv)**

This is a variation on the same theme (it still takes the input as a pointer to the beginning of a NUL-terminated ASCII string), but it pulls out all the stops to really optimize for size:

- It uses the ultra-compact x86 string instructions. In this case, `lods`, which loads a byte into `al` from the address in `rsi`, and also increments `rsi` to point to the next byte, using a single-byte encoding.

  - In order to know whether to increment or decrement the source pointer, the `rsi` instruction implicitly depends on the direction flag (`DF`). Normally, you'd need to explicitly clear that flag with the `cld` instruction, but, in this case, since we're running on a *nix-like operating system, per the challenge, we can assume it is already clear. (Also, when you're defining a custom calling convention, the state of the flags can be part of that; see below.)
- It uses a custom calling convention so that we can (A) take the input string in the `rsi` register, which is what the `lods` instruction expects, saving us from having to copy it from one register to another, and (B) build the result in a custom register (`edx`), freeing up `eax` to use as a scratch register (because this is what the `lods` instruction uses as an implicit destination operand).
- The `lods` instruction is only loading a single byte, so it only modified the low-order byte of the `eax` register (`al`). But the `lea` instruction that we use to perform multiple arithmetic operations in a single instruction only works on the full 64-bit register, so we need to make sure that the high values are clear. We could do this with an explicit `movzx` after the `lods` instruction, but that would consume a lot of bytes. So, instead, we do it once, outside of the loop, with a single `xor` instruction. This clears the entire `rax` register, which works because we only ever touch the low-order byte (`al`).

  - Another neat trick falls out of this: because we don't touch the high-order byte (`ah`), it's guaranteed to be zero through all iterations of our loop, so we can compare (`cmp`) the source pointer (string) to `ah` instead of comparing it to a literal 0, which saves us one byte in the encoding.

```
SumDigits:
  --          ; cld                           ; can assume DF is always clear on Linux)
  31 C0         xor    eax, eax               ; eax  = 0 (al = 0, ah = 0)
  31 D2         xor    edx, edx               ; edx  = 0 (holds result)
Loop:
  AC            lods                          ; al   = BYTE PTR [rsi]
  8D 54 02 D0   lea    edx, [rdx + rax - '0'] ; edx += (eax - '0')
  38 26         cmp    BYTE PTR [rsi], ah     ; is BYTE PTR [rsi] == ah (which is 0)?
  75 F7         jne    Loop                   ; loop back if not equal (non-zero)
  C3            ret                           ; result is in edx
```

The custom calling convention is a pretty major "cheat" here, but it's not unusual in the "real world" to use a custom calling convention when writing code in assembly. If you're going to call it from C, you need to take steps to match the standard C calling convention, but who says we're calling it from C?! We don't need no stinkin' C! :-)

Comment: Yes, you're right about the stdin/stout requirement, as the challenge author explicitly allowed in the question comments "function declaration" (which I and most interpreted as standard I/O rules)

Comment: I don't think empty string needs to be handled based on the challenge requirement: "given a non-negative integer", which an empty string isn't. Also a fully custom calling convention isn't cheating at all, per the x86 golfing tips page.

Answer (score 6):

## MATL, 3 bytes

```
!Us
```

Try it out at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=%21Us&inputs=%27123%27&version=22.7.4)

**Explanation**

```
      % Implicitly read in first input, a 1 x N string
!     % Flip it so that it is N x 1 character array (one character per row)
U     % Convert each row from a string to a number
s     % Sum the resulting N x 1 numeric array
      % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal 3.0.0-beta.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 9 bytes

```
'%%O48-/+
```

[Try it online! (link is to literate version)](https://vyxal.github.io/#WyJsIiwiIiwiIiwiJyUlIG9yZCA0OCAtIGZvbGQtICsgIiwiMjAwMDAwMDAwNCJd)

Unlike my v2 answer, there is no sum flag, sum built-in, cast to int or cast to string built in in this version of vyxal (because it's a beta release - what do you expect?).

### Explained

```
'%%O48-/+
'%%        ## Format the input as a string
   O48-    ## get the ordinal value of each character and subtract 48 to get the digit value
       /+  ## fold by addition
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
SO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/2P//f0MjYwA)

Comment: 2 bytes alternative: `1ö` (useful if you want to sum the digits of numbers within a list, since `1ö` is 1 byte less than `€SO`). :) For this challenge it's just an alternative though. 

Answer (score 5):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 14 bytes

```
digits(10)+sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcs5DoQwEATAnJfYIvFcnumA36xYOeAQmPcbKq/zOvqxj3VJ49f@rd@JSp7vZxt5ms6r7T2tSUjJwNXEAg5hCa1cVSSEHVY4QglOFQKIGxULLnCF6hdzHi8)

`digits(x, y)` converts `y` into digits in base `x` and `sum` performs sum. Therefore, `digits(10)` is a partial function that becomes `y => digits(10, y)` and `+ sum` chains it with `sum` so an input will be called with `digits(10)(...)` first, and then the result is called with `sum(...)`.

This is 6 bytes shorter than the straightforward `x=>sum(digits(10,x))`.

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, <s>32</s> <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```
=SUM(0+(0&MID(A1,ROW(A:A),1)))
```

Input in cell `A1`.

*Thanks to **user117069** and **EngineerToast** for the two bytes saved*.

Comment: You might save a byte by summing only up to row 99. The rules only require accepting input up to 10^100, not explicitly including 10^100.

Comment: Ah, ok. I've always interpreted "up to" as "up to and including" when not told otherwise, though your interpretation does make more sense. Thanks a lot, will amend.

Comment: You can save another byte with `ROW(A:A)`.

Comment: @EngineerToast Ah, of course! I'd never use that in a real situation due to the inefficiency, but here every byte counts, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>29</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```c
f(i){i=i?i%10+f(i/10):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOtM20z5T1dBAG8jTNzTQtDKwrv2vnJmXnFOakqpgU1ySkpmvl2HHlZlXopCbmJmnoclVzaUABAVFQKE0DSXVlJg8JR2FNA1DI2NNTWvschYWFjjlDA2MTECStf8B)

*-2 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

*-2 bytes thanks to c--*

Takes input as `int`.

C's `int` isn't large enough for the last test case.

<s>The bracket around the ternary is truly awful. Wish I could remove that.</s> Thanks c-- again.

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>38</s> 36 bytes (no recursion).

```c
a;f(i){for(a=0;i;i/=10)a+=i%10;a=a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dclBDoIwEEDRfU/RYEhmomKLLpqM9SRuJq3VSbAYxBXh7BX38pf/hf09hFKYEghOqR@AvSEhOXhrkLdeamuIPdNcNpJD94k3fX6PUfrmcVGSR/1kyYBqUnrpNSwrQVXHa652OoFtj4j035xzq2ZNe/rhXL4)

*-2 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

Takes input as `int`.

C's `int` isn't large enough for the last test case.

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 56 bytes (no recursion) (outgolfed by [c--](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258280/108879) using recursion).

```c
a,n;f(char*s){for(a=0,n=strlen(s);n--;++s)a+=*s-48;a=a;}
```

Takes input as string

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYzBjoIwFEX3fAVhMkkrYNq@V/peOvglbpoiSuJUQ3Fl/HaGzF7v6uSe3Bvbc4zrGprkRxEvYd5l@Rxvswi9alKfl/l6SiJLn9rW13WWoe53uUXyoQ/@tX5NKV4fw6n8ycsw3faXQzGlpfwNUxKyeBbllvu8VaOovodjqppyI22gktK/sUT0wWpl8IMGjdqy6SxYYsdggLAzHQIQGMdWGSLU7HTHwAzOamXJKHbIiNvw//q1/gE)

Comment: Your first two answers should be able to drop the `/1` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Giuseppe yeah, had a brainfart

Comment: you can reorder the first expression to remove the parentheses: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOtM20z5T1dBAG8jTNzTQtDKwrv2vnJmXnFOakqpgU1ySkpmvl2HHlZlXopCbmJmnoclVzaUABAVFQKE0DSXVlJg8JR2FNA1DI2NNTWvschYWFjjlDA2MTECStf8B)

Answer (score 4):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$1\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 0.823 bytes

```
S
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJTIiwiMTIzNDUiXQ==)

Builtin

Comment: What's with the logarithm? Did the scoring change?

Comment: @MarkReed Fig uses an irrational byte scoring system, which is allowed

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 9 bytes

```
sumdigits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctNCsIwEEDhqwxdNZBC5ifJzEIvIi4K0hJQGdq68PSx7t63eD5vbVq9L3CBvn9ej7a2Y@@z@/M7OkxX8K29jzOHPwZYRg8hwg2JI6hqBEwkERgFs1HJnNWqMbFKoSLMylQtJ1IVtIrF2IxrxpSVklUxkXO8h/4D)

Answer (score 4):

## Typescript Type System + `hotscript`, <s>92</s> 87 bytes

```typescript
import{Pipe,S,T}from"hotscript"
type _<U>=Pipe<U,[S.Split<"">,T.Map<S.ToNumber>,T.Sum]>
```

I just found out about this library that basically turns the Typescript Type System into a full-on functional programming language and it's amazing

Saved 5 bytes by taking input as a string instead of a number

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgVAQwM4AIASKBmUIgEQAWEMSAxlMGDHgFAwCeYApigPoA8AqgHwC8aAOgAKlJlwA0AbUEBlATLAAbYDHZ483cYIAqAgLIIw7WQO0QAcgFcQAIyZRNO+dYC63GnUYsoTJAEYUXjY1PwAmAGYNGgB6aJR4gD0Afk9mFB8kUMDgvAAOfKjY+JRk1O9fcOyOPD8ABlCAFkK4xKSgA)

```typescript
import{Pipe,S,T}from"hotscript"
type _<U>=           // define hotscript lambda with string argument U
Pipe<U,[             // pipe U to:
  S.Split<"">,       //   split on "" (= character list)
  T.Map<S.ToNumber>, //   map each letter to number
  T.Sum              //   sum 
]>                   // end pipe
```

Comment: you forgot to update the playground link and golfed snippet

Comment: @ASCII-only fixed, thanks

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 6 bytes

```
.
$*
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcsxDsJADATA3u8IEkqBzl77vPuCfAMKChqKKP8/mH7O9/X5vtbtfjzXw7bdfC0PGEnzEWnw9FLMQlEtBJgzZgJEtGoEma72KUjo8lGMoU5l/uMP) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.
$*
```

Convert each digit to unary.

```
1
```

Convert the sum to decimal.

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <strike>12</strike> 10 bytes

Tacit Julia strikes again!

```
sum∘digits
```

Explanation:

```
digits: take an integer and return a vector of its digits in base 10 (default)
∘: function composition
sum: sum a collection
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v9i2uDT3UceMlMz0zJJiLkMjY4UaO4ViEFFQlJlXkpP3/z8A)

-2 thanks to MarcMush

Comment: You can remove `s=`

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$2 \log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.646 bytes

```
dS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLUoIhDCh_wWJDI2MIEwA)

```
d    digits of input
 S   calculate sum
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -p, 19 bytes

```perl
s/./$s+=$&/ge;$_=$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctNCsIwEAbQywQ3UpP5y8yH9CyuShHEBuP5Hfv2b2yfl2XOeqtlXtdyqft2L4@1zEwhJQN3Ews4hCW0c1eREHZY4wglOHUIIG7ULLjBFapn/B3j@zzeM5fxBw)

Comment: `s/./$\+=$&/ge}{` for 15

Answer (score 3):

## x86-64 Linux assembly, 18 bytes

Lazy C translation. Follows calling convention of System V AMD64 ABI: input null-terminated string in rdi, output in rax.

```
sum_digits:
        xor     eax, eax            ; sum = 0
L:
        movsx   edx, BYTE [rdi]     ; c = *str
        inc     rdi                 ; ++str
        lea     eax, [rax-48+rdx]   ; sum += c - '0'
        cmp     BYTE [rdi], 0
        jne     L                   ; while (*str)
        ret
```

Objdump:

```
0000000000401110 <sum_digits>:
  401110:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax

0000000000401112 <L>:
  401112:   0f be 17                movsx  edx,BYTE PTR [rdi]
  401115:   48 ff c7                inc    rdi
  401118:   8d 44 10 d0             lea    eax,[rax+rdx*1-0x30]
  40111c:   80 3f 00                cmp    BYTE PTR [rdi],0x0
  40111f:   75 f1                   jne    401112 <L>
  401121:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: This appears to be 18 bytes, not 16. I think you may have forgotten to count the initial `xor` instruction outside of the loop? Also, fun fact, this is *almost* exactly the machine code that GCC will generate for the "obvious" C code when optimizing for size (`-Os`): [Godbolt demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hT6GzrKfq) (it swaps the order of the `cmp` and `lea`; the advantage of that is unclear, but at least it's not harmful, since the `cmp` with a memory operand isn't going to be able to macro-fuse with the `jne` anyway).

Comment: @CodyGray you're right about counting the xor. I think I got confused with a program starting at _start being initialized with zeros in most registers https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/181407#181407

Comment: The comment indexing with `i` is also misleading too. I started with assembly-like C and cheated by seeing what the compiler generated which is why they're so similar

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 17 bytes

```
->x{x.digits.sum}
```

This defines an anonymous function that accepts a single input (a number), breaks it up into an array of digits, then sums this array and returns the result

Answer (score 3):

## Rust, <s>54</s>  <s>47</s> 30 bytes

```rust
|n|n.map(|b|b as u64-48).sum()
```

A function that takes a `std::str::Bytes` and returns a `u64`. For the purpose of this challenge, I consider `std::str::Bytes` to be an iterator of ASCII-characters, which meets our general criteria for a string.

Previous versions:

```rust
|mut n|{let mut s=0;while n>0{s+=n%10;n/=10;}s}
```

```rust
|n|n.to_string().bytes().map(|d|u64::from(d)-48).sum()
```

Comment: [-5 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=vZBBTsMwEEXFMjnFUAlqo6SyPXZiU8Ex2CBUJSKpIhEDsbNApCdhkwUcqpwGh6QSJ2A2ozfzZ770Pz673vnxeFFbaIvGEgrvcfRUeaivobbk0vmOQnoLPc_g5qv3daqPV4Md7KZ885UjdNMWL2QoB1Km5ZqtKRRuEtON61tC54vvs7toG0f1cwckPGzsPoHHZt_4XRBRaCzcx1FEVlxyoVAqgShWCaCiyTwXGDBbSGsdSMjTkgkZOF8QwxNlRKZQaZMbFKhlJjKJqFHkRjGhteQm55lBYzBXnCktmMmlkTIcTr78ZGz-oYKhYWwyfAjZQ6iocK7q_K56PSf1Ehj9m9j2V3aID3O84zj3Hw)

Comment: [Here's one using only 34 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=vZFBTsMwEEXFMjnF0E1tKYlsj53YqWDBNRBUiZpUkYiB2Fkg0pOw6QIOVU6DQ1qJEzCb0Zv5ni99f3wOo_PHE2st9FVnCYX3OHpqPLQltJY4vytL54eyvHvzjaOQ3sLIc7j5Gn2b6tNqspPN-uqFTPVE6rReszWFys0imrmxJ3RRfl89Rps4ap8HCEeHzu4T2HX7zm-DiEJn4T6OIrLikguFUglEsUoAFU2WucCA-Zm01oGEvCyZkIGLM2I4oozIFSptCoMCtcxFLhE1isIoJrSW3BQ8N2gMFoozpQUzhTRShoezL78Ym3-oYGgYmw0fQvwQKqqcawa_bV6vSXsOLKvnLyCU_k1u8ys_xIcl5uNx6T8), but it can feel a bit like cheating.

Comment: @JSorngard Thanks. I think choosing the correct input and output types is an important part of solving a challenge, especially for Rust.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n&&n%10+f(n/10|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9mC0R5tnZ5amp5qoYG2mkaefqGBjUGmv@T8/OK83NS9XLy0zXSNAyNjDU1uVDFLCwsMMQMDYxMNDX/AwA)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 21 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n&&n*9%9-f(n/~9)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9mC0R5tnZ5amp5WpaqlrppGnn6dZaa/5Pz84rzc1L1cvLTNdI0DI2MNTW5UMUsLCwwxAwNjEw0Nf8DAA)

It is shorter, but with floating point errors...

Comment: IMO the output of `2` for the input `3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592` is slightly more than a simple "floating point error" :P

Comment: @Kaddath that is floating point errors. The input number is too large. A difference of 300 is much smaller compared with the input number.

Comment: Yes I was just joking, my attempt with PHP gave 78, it depends on your max int value I guess, anyway most answers just ignored the 10^100 integer rule and take the input as a string

Comment: This is the most beautiful thing I have ready today. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```perl6
say [+] get.comb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVIhWjtWIT21RC85Pzfp/39DI2MA)

`get()`: gets a single line from stdin (parens not required)

<s>`.univals()`: maps a string of numerical unicode chars to a list of their values.  I'm just using it in place of `.split("")`, which would be 2 bytes longer.</s>

`.comb`: splits out to list of characters (thanks
[@Mark Reed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4133/mark-reed))

`[+]`: reduces the list by addition.

`say`: writes to stdout

Comment: You don't need `split` in Raku anyway; just use `get.comb`.

Comment: @MarkReed Thanks, edited to add that.  I saw `.comb`s documentation, but I didn't notice there was a nullary version.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Comment: Fun tips, `.sum` is the same size as `[+]`, so this could be `get.comb.sum.say` for the same amount of bytes, or `*.comb.sum.say` in function form

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), <strike>9 7</strike> 6 bytes

```
~c%+#q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@vUzfQ1VYu/P/f0MgYAA)

Having read through the [Default I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5330/91625) thread, it seems my "fun extra" answer is actually valid as a submission. Note that since the output in this version is an exit code, POSIX-compatible systems (including TIO; please let me know if there's a better site for this) will only care about the least significant byte and as such display the result mod 256 (as per the [Funge-98 spec](https://catseye.tc/view/funge-98/doc/funge98.markdown#Flow)).

### Explanation

`~`: Read next character.

`c%`: Push 12, then take input character mod 12. This gives the number represented. Suggested by Jo King (previous iteration subtracted 48 from the number with `'0-`).

`+`: Add that to the current total (initially implicitly 0).

`#q`: Do nothing if control flow is LTR, quit and return top of stack as exit code if RTL.

Due to wrapping, this is a loop. At EOF, `~` reflects, thus executing the last portion RTL.

### Previous version

```
~'0-+2j@.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcsxDoQwDATA51CgoNhrx96OtyABEgWioaC5r@cQ3TSzrNt97mthluv52PtvqGXUY556h5g4tTk8GYQirWkzIKFBr5ppwpBGkAiX6qmVYTR74x8)

#### Explanation

As above, but replace `#q` with:

`2j@.`: Jumps over the exit and print if control flow is LTR, prints top of stack as an integer then exits if RTL (push 2, jump, exit, print).

Comment: `'0-` can be `c%`

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 5 bytes

```
+/⍎¨⍞
```

Explanation:

- `⍞`  reads standard input as a character vector
- `⍎¨` converts each digit to its numeric value
- `+/` computes the sum

[Try it online!](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=%7B%2B%2F%E2%8D%8E%C2%A8%E2%8D%95%E2%8D%B5%7D%C2%A8123%20888%201024%20%273141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592%27&run)

Comment: You need `⍞` instead of `⍕`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxDcJADAXQPqsgxNnfPvuPEykSTSSuZQJowgjUzJFRbpELKV/x5rZel@e8Pu6jv19tXG59@@y/vn1PjzZBTJxaHZ4MQpFWtRqQ0KAXzTRhSCVIhEvx1MIwmv3jAQ "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: I was assuming the usual conventions where "take as input" could be arguments to a function instead of literal I/O.

Comment: It does say *Your program should take input from standard input (stdin) and output the result to standard output (stdout).* but even if your solution is taken as a function, it'd not work, as it'd be a [3-train](https://apl.wiki/3-train), and equivalent to `{(+/⍵)⍎¨(⍕⍵)}` and even if taken as a snippet (which isn't allowed per site rules), it'd fail on large numbers due to precision.

Answer (score 3):

### Pascal, 114 bytes

This is a full `program` according to ISO standard 7185 “Standard Pascal”.
The built-in data type `integer` comprises (at least) all integral values in the range `−maxInt..maxInt`.
The value of `maxInt` is *implementation-defined*.
In order to successfully test values up to and including one googol you will need a processor (this refers to the specific combination of machine, compiler, OS, etc.) defining `maxInt` ≥ 10<sup>100</sup>.

```pascal
program p(input,output);var x,y:integer;begin y:=0;read(x);repeat y:=y+x mod 10;x:=x div 10 until x=0;write(y)end.
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
program digitSum(input, output);
    var
        x, digitSum: integer;
    begin
        digitSum := 0;
        read(x);
        
        repeat
        begin
            digitSum := digitSum + x mod 10;
            x := x div 10;
        end
        until x = 0;
        
        write(digitSum);
    end.
```

Because in Pascal `mod` is defined to always yield a non-negative result, `digitSum` works incorrectly for negative inputs.
Injecting an `x := abs(x);` prior the loop will resolve this issue.

---

Another method is of course to *process characters*.
In Pascal it is guaranteed that the characters `'0'` through `'9'` are in ascending order and consecutive, thus `ord('9') − ord('0')` is guaranteed to yield the `integer` value `9`.

```pascal
program p(input,output);var x:integer;begin x:=0;while not EOF do begin x:=x+ord(input^)-ord('0');get(input)end;write(x)end.
```

Input must not be followed by a newline, or replace the `EOF` by `EOLn`.
This `program` is ≥ 124 bytes

Comment: [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##HclLCoAwDADRvafIskJ1p4I5TexHQksqUbS3r@huHnPQ6SgP8XCt3aRAtq7npSw7JivrU9TjFnYW1EDeUI@xKFRgAQJfuv/BTdlUm3pkcUa@COLxUb6CkR9ja8s8vQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), 35 bytes

```bc
for(;i<length(a);i++)b+=a/10^i%10;b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYvLCsIwEADv/YqACA09mM0mzS61vyJ9RQ1olKb1In577UGwx2Fmun4Z/DlEL4ZwSfM9b@U71KrqarWcH2NehePNx8t0XUUVikJ2Rd0eQJ3CHtZq@WRZrH8raJR/IqINgdJmgwgGLOvSoiV2jBrJlLo0iITasVWayAA7KBmZ0VlQlrRiZ9iYdZRZthNNbETfTv3VJzH6aR6jeLW32Ys8zc/n6FNaRaOaJJcv)

Using the default `scale=0` i.e. no decimals, divide by `1,10,100,...`  successively (`a/10^i`), and `%10` to add only the last digit to `b`. When the `for` loop finishes, print the sum. `;b`

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 5 bytes

```
+/10\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9LWNzSI4eJKUzA0MDIB0RYWFgA0VARb)

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, 42 bytes

This new and improved version supports BigInt, as well as numbers and strings. It uses tsh's idea, but it first changes the type and uses the ES10 BigInt. (It also happens to be the shortest I could come up with!)

```js
a=n=>eval("x=BigInt(n);x&&x%10n+a(x/10n)")
```

I also tried playing around and created these functions:

```js
// BigInt/String/Number
b=n=>eval("l=0;(n+[]).split('').forEach(t=>l+=+t);l")
// String only
c=n=>eval("l=0;n.split('').forEach(t=>l+=+t);l")
// BigInt only
d=n=>n&&n%10n+d(n/10n)
// String/Number
e=n=>+n&&+n%10+e(+n/10|0)
```

Comment: 34 bytes: [`a=n=>(x=BigInt(n))&&x%10n+a(x/10n)`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWN5USbfNs7TQqbJ0y0z3zSjTyNDXV1CpUDQ3ytBM1KvSBtCZE5d7k_Lzi_JxUvZz8dI1EDWNDEyNTSyMzU2NTC0tNqBqYqQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 39 bytes

```powershell
param([string]$i)($i|% t*y)-join"+"|iex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXI7q4pCgzLz1WJVNTQyWzRlWhRKtSUzcrPzNPSVupJjO14v///4aW5kYmZsaGZhZmxhamAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Leaf-Lang](https://gitlab.com/Breadleaf/leaf-lang), 95 bytes

`macro p pop pop end""input splitString 0:s""=0=while p p toNumber s+:s""=0=stop p p 1p s print`

### Explaination

Leaf Lang is a lang I made in my free time in college. It is a stack-based programming language. It can be hard to understand, so I wrote a step-by-step golf of my solution.

#### The readable solution

```
"" input splitString # split input into array of strings
0 : sum              # sum = 0
"" = 0 =             # loop condition
while
        pop pop pop pop      # clean stack of condition
        toNumber sum + : sum # sum = sum + toNumber
        "" = 0 =             # loop condition
stop

pop pop pop pop # clean stack of condition
pop             # clean stack of stop condition

sum # add sum to stack
print
```

#### Compressed readable solution, 109 bytes

`""input splitString 0:sum""=0=while pop pop pop pop toNumber sum+:sum""=0=stop pop pop pop pop pop sum print`

#### Macro optimization #1, 98 bytes

`macro p pop end""input splitString 0:s""=0=while p p p p toNumber s+:s""=0=stop p p p p p s print`

This uses a macro to shorten the long chains of `pop` calls.

#### Macro optimization #2, 96 bytes

`macro p pop pop end""input splitString 0:s""=0=while p p toNumber s+:s""=0=stop p p pop s print`

#### The final golf code, 95 bytes

`macro p pop pop end""input splitString 0:s""=0=while p p toNumber s+:s""=0=stop p p 1p s print`

The final code abuses my parser to push a `1` to the stack then call the `p` macro to essentially make a single `pop` call.

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 31 bytes

```sh
for i (${(s::)1})((n+=i));<<<$n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcu9DsIgFEDhvU/B0AHiwv2Deys@jsQumIguNn12Whe/8STn2x@j@rBNn9bvb9dGfb7c6vy8@b4sAfbgfbvc1hCupZS5jX2qDv7iz1kIGMQwCYlaNkJSTpiYSAmzSURVBsuQjMwoC0RRjJbZmM9xjAM)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-F -E`, 18 bytes

```perl
$s+=$_ for@F;say$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcs9CgIxEAbQq2yRTlYyf5n5EMFqO88gFgqCmGVj4@Udff1bb9vTMsvYHctluvfttBzG9VNGppCSgZuJBRzCEtq4qUgIO6xyhBKcGgQQN6oWXOEK1X/89vX96K@R8zLNZ9tXqj8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 1 [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ì
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=7A&input=MTAyNA)

`ì` gets the digits of the number, the `-x` flag sums the resulting array

Comment: Who downvoted this? Can they explain themselves?

Comment: Well, I am going to upvote it @Jacob cz this is one of the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 15 bytes

```arturo
$=>[∑digits&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?iqVW2w)

Even though the question says input and output must be via standard IO, the author of the question said functions are allowed in the comments. So this is a function.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 3 bytes

```
ＩΣＮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctLCsIwEADQ68SFkPllZnDpyo0IniAWQaGtkiZef@zbv@lV2/Spc8StvdeeznXr6T6WdFm/o1/H8ni2dNidIggYxLEIibk6IRkXLExkhOqS0YzBFYqTO6lAFsPsys68xzj@5j8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  Ｎ Input number
 Σ  Sum of digits
Ｉ   Cast to string
    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## Standard ML, 43 bytes

```
(foldl op+ 0)o map(fn x=>ord x-48)o explode
```

Lack of sum function strikes again

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
DS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98l@P///4ZGxgA)

```
D    digits
 S   sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 3 bytes

```
$+a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhaLVbQTISyowNJoQyPjWCgHAA)

```
$+    sum of
      (the digits of)
  a   the input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Hebigo](https://github.com/gilch/hebigo), 25 bytes

```
print:sum:map: int input:
```

(It compiles to the following Python.)

```python
print(
  sum(
    map(
      int,
      input())))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 19 bytes

```
Total@IntegerDigits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcs7DsIwEAXAK3l/9r4CKQUNHQUdSmFFJlgiQQp7f8MBqEez1Xi2rUZf6nicxu0d9TVd9mhrO8597fEZ16Pvcf8jk5CSgbOJOQqExTVzVhEXLrDE7koolCGAFKNkzglFofqL8/gC)

```
Total@IntegerDigits@3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592
```

315

Comment: @The Thonnu,   Thanks for the edits,

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 31 bytes

```powershell
%{$s=0;$_|% *ay|%{$s+="$_"};$s}
```

Input comes from the pipeline

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcvLCsMgEEDRX5FgEPoA56HOEPItoRShi0BKXIRS8@22rg53cd/bkffyyut6f257bg6Q3M04EemAR@4SMATFGCiIJiUk4YiRiYQwafAowqAJopIqpQA@CHpNrMz/0Znaxq8ts5/sUkdzeXxq7@s82GU4J1vO1n4)

```powershell
%{$s=0;$_|% *ay|%{$s+="$_"};$s}
%{                            } # % is an alias for the cmdlet ForEach-Object; input (the string containing the number) comes from the pipeline and will be in $_
  $s=0;                         # initialize the final sum
       $_|% *ay                 # takes the input string and passes it to "ForEach-Object -MemberName ToCharArray": turns the string into an array of characters. This is shorter than a cast using [char[]]$_
               |%{$s+="$_"};    # pass the single characters to yet another ForEach-Object which sums up the total. The current character in $_ must be turned into a single-char string by wrapping it in double quotes;
                                # without that, PS would add up the character's byte code since the left operand (the sum) is an integer.
                            $s  # output the sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 1 [byte](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
Σ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##DcuxEYAwDAPAPtPElh1L49AABRwNG7EPKwW@/3O59@061jnfZ05zNJLNukeDhaV8JJIqwcEYPgIgvJTdyTCVDUFCpfWkd1Uo4o8f)

**Explanation:**

```python
Σ  # Sum the digits of the (implicit) input-integer
   # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 150 bytes

```
{(({})<><((()()()()()){})>)({}(<>))<>{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}{}<>([{}()]{}{})<>({}<((()()()()()){})>(<>))<>([()]{()<(({})){({}[()])<>}{}>}{}<><{}{}>)}<>
```

Not sure if this counts, because it exceeds TIO's 60s time limit for the `3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592`
test case, as its' time complexity is linear. Theoretically, given enough time, it should output the right answer. This answer is extremely similar in format to my answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258411/38662).

```
{                                                                               #  loop while top of left stack is not 0
(({})<><((()()()()()){})>)({}(<>))<>{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}{}<>([{}()]{}{})<>    #  add the result of modulo 10 of the top value of the left stack to the top value on the right stack
({}<((()()()()()){})>(<>))<>([()]{()<(({})){({}[()])<>}{}>}{}<><{}{}>)          #  integer division by 10 on left stack
}                                                                               #  end loop
<>                                                                              #  switch to right stack
                                                                                #  implicit output of active (right) stack
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYw7CoBADESvM1MIIiIIIRcRCy0EUSxsw559HX@VkhDCfN64D/NWTOuw5BxAJJobAL5DSU4ZMKfMO8TQ7cBeSoqkNUenEPtIF0T@l/MwcDYDtD@WXzA7MU59OTdtXZUH)

Comment: [144 bytes](https://tio.run/##bYwxCoRQDESvM1MIIiIIIRcRC7dYEMXCNuTs3/mKzbIkkGQy8z7nsh7Nd1@2UgKIJAx00hwA36Iez1sjcgJnOTJSLecUKSV01Jyk36zDHmZNBmj/WH7DrGKc2koZxr5rLw "Brain-Flak – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
ẹ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcs7CsJAEADQqwxpXWHntzPT6EHEQi20EASbIGKTImDnUWwszG02F1l9/dtfd4fT7Xw5Urv3HSxX0PXreXzPw1Cn56N@Xq1O30VrGyRO4O4JMJMkYBTUoKKsHhZM7FKoCLMzWWgmd8EwLMERbIpZnXKYhMg/bn8)

#### Explanation

`ẹ` is a pretty disgusting built-in for a declarative logic language, but it’s useful. A "better" alternative would be `∋ᶠ` (find all elements) but it’s longer.

```
ẹ     Split into a list of elements
 +    Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 9 bytes (?)

```
sd←+/⊥⍣¯1
```

Some characters take probably more than 1 byte, but I am not sure how many...

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Usually for APL, a custom code page is used that makes the characters one byte each. I think [Dyalog Extended](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended) is the most common one.

Comment: How is this meant to be run? It doesn't read input; it doesn't result in `sd` being a callable dfn...

Comment: You don't need to count `sd←` but you do need to read from stdin in a UNIX environment. While NARS2000 has large integer support, and your algorithm would work there, it doesn't run under UNIX, so you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```
def c={("$it"as List).sum{it as int}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TctLCsIwFEDRuasIxUEzkbxPkvcG7sBNSP0Q0FaaKEjp2mNmdnQ5g3ufp@nzrfVyvZnhuPTdPpXunM0p5WIP@f1cUjHNaSzrWl9z62M0Qw9IdveniGwJDnlrAgavGDx50aiEJBwwMJEQRvUORRg0QlBSpejBeUGnkZW5jbb@AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [KamilaLisp v0.2](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/kamilalisp), 15 (APL SBCS)

```
$(⌿.← +)∘:⊙⍫∘⍫∧
```

Equivalent to `$(foldl1 +)@:parse-number@str:explode`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 23 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/BSsQwEAbg@z7FsKeGQDeTSZqM0AXFiwdPPoDE3VIi3VpslIL47DW7XQShJrfh@5N/xkPowvz28tocEjyG2EMzpaY/jnA7DF/wGToYP073sY1pvIGn9B77tt7DXWwf@gQ1zFO9n8pTGIrnMowXJ8qcmIcsU9cXv@lii5qM3Qqoa0ArYLcDlFqSNNLCebRZyajFKwGXkzNqjSHiAklcGcp887O0xtm7hWsjFs7SSwfnwZq3hjT@aW5za8rt8d/mhAYt68qS9eyYNHlT6coQedKOrdLeG2SHFRMzOYvKeq3YGTYmB6/75P823/MP)

```
x=>x.map(_.asDigit).sum
```

Answer (score 2):

[KAP](https://kapdemo.dhsdevelopments.com/), 7 characters, 11 bytes:

```
+/@0-⍨⍕
```

[Try it online](https://kapdemo.dhsdevelopments.com/clientweb2/#(%2B%2F%400-%E2%8D%A8%E2%8D%95)%203141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592).

It appears that one needs bigint support to properly answer this question. If strings are allowed then the last character can be removed from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 40 bytes

```lua
a=0(...):gsub('.',load'a=...+a')print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcttCsIwDADQ47RFKc1Xkwg7TGQwhKGi7vxxfx@8/YjMWEbtvbfb9j3utfRy3V@xllhOvERp78/j@avRMpOAQRynkJirE5LxxMlERqguA80YXGE6uZMKDDEcruzMZ/wD)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2.5 bytes

```
+`@10
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxBCoNAEAQfJIGd6Zmd6ZtPEUFBCLkkeU0ue1nyJn-joLeioOr3f23z_FzerfXvZ31kH6ZRysW3avsIMXFqdXgyCEVa1WpAQoNeNNOEIZUgES7FUwvDaHaG1-gA)

### Explained

```
+`@10
+      # Sum of
 `@    # input converted to
   10  # base 10 (basically, list of digits)
```

Comment: Nice.  You can save a nibble by using the default (```~```) value for "to base" (`\`@`), which is 10: [try it](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxCoNQEAUPJIG_-3b_7us8iggJBMQmSZuLpPmF4pm8jYLphoGZ3zY_x3G6v1pbP-_HLZdu6L8X_k3be4iJU6vDk0Eo0qpWAxIa9KKZJgypBIlwKZ5aGEazM7xGBw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>75</s> <s>65</s> 56 bytes

```
listen to N
cut N
X's 0
while N
let X be+roll N-0

say X
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

```
listen to N     :Read input string into variable N
cut N           :Split to an array
X's 0           :Initialise X as 0
while N         :While N is not empty
let X be+       :  Increment X by
  roll N        :    Pop the first element from N
  -0            :    Subtract an 0 to cast it to an integer
                :End while loop
say X           :Output X
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Shasta <sup>v0.0.11</sup>](https://github.com/jacobofbrooklyn/shasta/tree/432c10c034c90302285be4ac61e227d404b53adb), 27 bytes

```
{(eval(join(split$"")"+"))}
```

`{...}` Function of argument $

`(eval ...)` Evaluate as JavaScript

`(join ... "+")` Join on "+"

`(split $ "")` Characters of the input string

Alternative 27 bytes:

```
{(sum(map(split$"")number)}
```

The sum of mapping each character of the input string to number.

Online interpreter will be set up very soon; for now, you can test this by following instructions from the README on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.unicode`, 18 bytes

```
[ >dec 48 v-n Σ ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY4xTsNAEEV7n-LTs-uAUiRGipQGZClKE1EhZJn12I5Y7zqz4yDOQmMJkQNwEKi5DQ7bUM2M_p___tupLo14Hn--73f59i5DV0qr-5IDcdyPdDYEBDoM5AwF9Ewirz3vneCZ2JGNzsHtja8IN8i3GRpv62S9yde7DKuKDNzQPRGvgkyPDYAL3P6xMdPLJZSaCIRWpA9ZmlbeBB27nTO15yY13gk5SV88V6ooGimKKffyX2PdSmeT5Gp2Pf8YpFaLz4fIni9wVA5f73iMwsmU1kLHYxzj_AU)

- `>dec` Convert the input to a string
- `48 v-n` Subtract 48 from each code point
- `Σ` Sum

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 3 bytes

```
S&+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z9YTfv/f0MDIxNDAyCwBAA)

Breaks STDIN into digits and pushes onto the stack, then uses `&+` to sum them.  Prints the stack as a number be default when the code exits.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 11 bytes

```
`1/{~}%{+}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctLCsIwEADQvacIAwVtQDOfJDOK4D1UEISIIFqquxCvHn37d3s9yvs636dPr/2Cm/ptQ/Vt7G1bdosjEjtVdRhIHKNgNEqRo1o2JlZJlIRZmbLFQKqCljEZm3GOGKJSsCwm8o/nui5QlnDwsAIPbu/An3wbnmP/AQ)

A function which takes a single integer as input. Link includes test cases.

## Explanation

```
`1/{~}%{+}* # whole function
`           # convert the input into a string
  /         # split into groups of size
 1          # 1
   { }%     # for each value in the split groups...
    ~       # eval it
       {+}* # sum this `eval`ed array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
ssMz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcu5EYBADAPAls6W/KgI@iBk5kigecPmez33ObP38c7AaCHPQLRKcDTTk0DDS7G8m6ayFCRU2Ir2paLIP34)

Alternatively there's [sjQT](https://tio.run/##Dcu7DYBQDAPAlV5i5@MxkBgCUSFBw/SB6@96n2PmPrd9BkYLeQaiVYKjmZ4EGl6K5d00laUgocJWtC8VRf7xAw) or just [ssM](https://tio.run/##Dcu5EYBADAPAXq6CsyU/KoI@CJmBhOoNm@/1PufMfR8zC0YLeQaiVYKjmZ4EGl6K7d00laUgocJ2tG8VRf5xfQ) if we're allowed to have quotes around the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 13 bytes

```
[: +/ 48 -~ a. I. ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw this and just had to give it a go with Java. I mean, I'm *not* going to win, but it's in good fun, right?
Using loops, assuming that we can have multiple inputs, including 0:

```
class D{public static void main(String[]a){int s=0;for(String t:a)for(char c:t.toCharArray())s+=c-48;System.out.println(s);}}
```

That gives 125 bytes, but if we assume some assumptions, we can surely get it lower. If we assume one and only input, we don't have to loop, so we can shorten it down further. But if we also stream, we get:

```
class D{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.println(a[0].chars().map(i->i-48).sum());}}
```

Which clocks in at 97 bytes.

That's not too bad for Java.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! Be sure to check out [Tips for golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java)

Comment: I think for Java submissions is is common to put the boilerplate into the header and use lambdas. Here is a 31 byte port of your solution using this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY2xTsMwEIZn8hSnTDYQi5YOkQoZkRiYOiKGI02Cg@1YvnOlqurKA/CIvEgwbcQUqbfdf/d9f487LPrt56itHwJDn3YVWRvVRlezHpy6Xmc@vhtdQ22QCF5QOzhkkIYYOeVP0@vDhoN23S08O266JlTQPo5UVKTqDwwkpLLohS4qXaxKqShaIcf1yTQ1TMLdoLdgU484G1/fAENH8pBdbfbEjVVDZOXTiY0T@WJ5D/Dz9Q053ECr0HuzP6W5lGf938yRZVnOkCm9SC7ulquZzpT@o8fsOP4C "Java (JDK) – Try It Online") (note: I don't know any Java, just based this off of other answers I've seen on this site)

Comment: Yeah, but it said it should be runnable from a command line. I just wanted to make usre it went with the rules. Your suggestion does shave off a lot of scaffolding for sure. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 44 bytes

```
=QUERY(,"select "&REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\B","+"))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [vemf](https://github.com/selaere/vemf), 6 bytes

```
ª-:48+
```

Input is a number literal.

[try it online](https://selaere.github.io/vemf/wasm/index.html?code=ImZpdmU&fmt=0), uses `:314159` as example

### Explanation

```
ª      ' represent as a codepage string
 -:48  ' subtract 48 from each codepoint
       ' (so the codepoints are all now 0-9)
     + ' sum list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java 8 (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 31 bytes

Very classic answer in Java

```java
s->s.chars().map(e->e-48).sum()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY87bsMwEER7n2LhiixEiD@JCyM@gVO5DFIwMuXQoShBpAwEgc@u0IHSzuybh73Zu63GycXb5Wudlo/gO@iCTQlerY/ws9sB@Jjd3NvOwakEAH8J9OScZx@vkOihhI/nZco2l4ETBHhZU3VMrPu0cyKUDXYirjq6ShnK0jIQuh6exKbcwPvoLzAU8bb99g52via6ac/fKbuBjUtmU6lziCSwnuwlV1yjaLTUBluUQhrViEZJaaRoUdfCGMWx5Q1KRNlqXmsjamwVKlXAPf1/4bH@Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 42 Bytes

```python
lambda x:sum(int(y) for y in list(str(x)))
```

[Try this code online](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsMgEEDRq7jUnTozOlPoTbJJKVIhMUEtxNPbdP15/xz9cxSY6bnMbd1f71Vdj/bddS5dD6PSUdVQuagtt65br/oyxsyz/nvS4NCR@EBALFHAA2PwAQEYfBSynhmdRBcERCCSs8TeSkRBvOG9@gE)

Comment: [-7 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcxNCsMgEEDhq7jUnc6PzhR6k24SijTQmGAsxNPbZP343t7bZys48vM1vtM6vydzPo7fapfSbHd5q6abpZijVXs6N/Z6h2wxUGCFyMiiSRFQKEIkREFIyh5EKGgKUVEVEwfPAl4TKdEFr9Uf "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: `lambda x:sum(map(int,str(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>33 (35!)</strike> 30 bytes

-5 thanks to c--.
No strings

```python
f=lambda n:n and n%10+f(n//10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qTyExL0UhT9XQQDtNI09f39BA839BUWZeiUaahqGRsabmfwA)

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk8hMS9FIU/V0EA7TSNPX9/QQPN/QVFmXolGmoahkbGm5n8A)

Comment: Since the lambda is recursive, it has to be named, so your answer is [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P942JzE3KSVRIc8qT9XQQDteI09f39BAMzNNIU8hNac4VcHgf0FRZl6JRryGoZGxpuZ/AA), or [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qTyExL0UhT9XQQDtNI09f39BA839BUWZeiUaahqGRsabmfwA) with my earlier suggestion.

Comment: I agree and have thought about this: it can not be legal to call something that is named for free.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 18 bytes

```cs
s=>s.Sum(a=>a-48);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/LSsNAGIXXyVP8BBcz0JbMLZmhphsxICguunAhLkKYtgFNZWbqhZCncOvT@SLxTwNKQSHDcIbzHb7Ufl77ZigPbX3ug2va7QyaNqyghAIGX6z8Yn14IlWxquZS0@XwUjkI1oeLyluPnda@AplIuGqPMNweAr1/gC6OSMK4SGaQ0dkYtNYYuJwSS7nEmE9JMMmU4ZkSSpvcCC60zHgmhdCC50alXGvJTM4yI4wRuWKp0jw1uTRSIohLgqlxq1/G8WbvbFXvgIy@ZBQbpdDuV57GKBjcexzhHY09h/9TYpku8aHZAEEGigIcxTyWojvXBHvdtJacJV@fH9Dh8pypHjrXJ0esx2Mfvf2LKE/6QDrc7@kPh19dhXpHLt9q@xyafQuWTnb/rdjFjfW@2trTtT7uh28)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) & coreutils, 21 bytes

```bash
fold -1|paste -sd+|bc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctLCsMwDAXAq2RfDJaeZOkdJ86HLAItuMvc3e3sp6/jmvN83/tS5Pms43ssZeyvp29zQkyc2hyeDEKR1rQZkNCgV800YUgjSIRL9dTKMJr94w8)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 51 bytes

```swift
let s={String($0+0).reduce(0){Int("\($1)")!+$0}}
```

Comment: You can remove the space between `i:` and `Int`. Also, you might want to use an online testing website like [Try It Online](//tio.run/#swift4) so other people can verify your code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 27 bytes

```
for(s=0;n>0;s+=n%10,n/=10);
```

Input as Integer (n)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Comment: Do note that input can't be in predefined variables - it needs to be read from stdin/argv (if using a full program) or taken from function/lambda arguments.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 0 bytes

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhYLlhQnJRfDOYZGxiYQNgA)

No bytes, that's right.

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 byte

```
S
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWC4OXFCclF0N5C5YYGhmbQNgA)

Alternatively, have a built-in.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=sum -pF`, 8 bytes

```perl
$_=sum@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcw7DsIwEAXAy9BGsvfj3RcJiSoVKVNTUVgKxMLm@ixwgJl2f@0acbqd@/txWSI4S1ZQUVaHgYldChVhdiaDJnKXDMsFDLBpTuqUYAKRH/wcbdTj2WNar7WPed5G3f95TG35Ag)